# Loop over 2 lists and print the result to a csv

Tags: java, spring, apache, csv, apache-commons

I have this issue where in i am trying to loop over 2 lists (of different lengths) and print the result to csv.

below is my code:(i have marked the line where i need help)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/do.download")
    public String download(Form form, Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            logger.debug("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + "Backup"+ ".csv");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-csheck=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            pw = response.getWriter();

            pw.println("carid,carname,carmodel,carcolor");

            car CarFromDB = new car(); 
            List<carDetails> CarDetailsFromDB = Collections.emptyList();
            List<carColor> carColorFromDB = Collections.empltyList();


            CarDetailsFromDB = Service.getcarDetails(CarFromDB);
            carColorFromDB =  Service.getcarColor(CarFromDB);


            for (carDetails cardetails : CarDetailsFromDB) {

                pw.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s", 
                        cardetails.getcarid(),
                        cardetails.getcarname(),
                        cardetails.getcarmodel(),
                        //get car color from the listcarColorFromDB which also has carid <--- this is where i need help 

                        ));
            }
            pw.flush();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStacktrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can have multiple colors per car.  If so, below you can see that you can loop through the colors inside the other loop and compare the carId's.  if they match, then add the color to the string.  Finally use that created string to be the last parameter for the println.  I fixed some formatting issues as well with names and capitalization.  Classes should be upper case and variables lower case.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/do.download")
public String download(Form form, Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        logger.debug("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + "Backup"+ ".csv");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-csheck=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        pw = response.getWriter();

        pw.println("carid,carname,carmodel,carcolor");

        Car carFromDB = new Car(); 
        List<CarDetails> carDetailsFromDB = new ArrayList<CarDetails>();
        List<CarColor> carColorFromDB = new ArrayList<CarColor>();


        carDetailsFromDB = Service.getCarDetails(carFromDB);
        carColorFromDB =  Service.getCarColor(carFromDB);


        for (CarDetails carDetails : carDetailsFromDB) {

            //loop through all the colors and find ones that match the carId for this carDetails
            // then concatenate them together with a "|"
            String colorsStr = "";
            for(CarColor color : carColorFromDB){
               if(color.getCarId() == carDetails.getCarId()){
                   colorsStr = colorsStr + "|" + color.toString();
               }
            }
            //chop off the first character which should be a "|" 
            colorsStr = colorsString.substring(1);


            pw.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s", 
                    carDetails.getCarId(),
                    carDetails.getCarName(),
                    carDetails.getCarModel(),
                    //get car color from the listcarColorFromDB which also has carid <--- this is where i need help 
                    colorsStr
                    ));
        }
        pw.flush();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStacktrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Did you change the class names in the other files?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can handle it...

1. Run a second loop inside the first for...

   ```
      for (carDetails cardetails : CarDetailsFromDB) {
              for (carColor carColor : carColorFromDB ) {
                 //match the car id from 2 objects and act   
              }

       }
   ```
2. Create a map with key as car id and value as `carColor`. Access the map inside for loop to get matching car color.